# Execute code each time x <= y while looping

Tags: php

I'm not exactly sure how to explain this but basically I have an x variable equal to the number of rows in a database and each time it is equal to 4 or less, run a piece of code.

So say I have 5 rows, I want to execute the code twice because x is equal to 4 once and then equal to 1. Same if I had 6 rows (4+2) 7 rows (4+3) or 8 rows (4+4).

Then, when I reached 9 rows (4+4+1), it would execute the code thrice. Etc...

The code I'm trying to run is a piece of HTML with some more PHP inside it. I want to create a new `<ul>` with the said code inside it each time the number of rows is equal to 4 or less as explained above.

The code as it is right now:

```
<div class="row-fluid well">
  <?php
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($num_rows <= 4) {
    ?>
    <ul class="minigames">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<li class='span3'>";
      if (logged_in() === false && !empty($row['app_about']) === true && strlen($row['app_about']) <= 100) {
        echo "<a href='#!' class='thumbnail minigamedesc' title='" . $row['app_name'] . "' data-content='" . $row['app_about'] . "<br /><br /><center><a href=\"./games.php?play_error#library\" class=\"btn btn-info\"><i class=\"icomoon-white icomoon-screen\"></i> Play in browser</a></center>'>";
      } else if (logged_in() === false && !empty($row['app_about']) === true && strlen($row['app_about']) >= 101) {
        $app_about = substr(strip_tags($row['app_about']), 0, 100);
        echo "<a href='#!' class='thumbnail minigamedesc' title='" . $row['app_name'] . "' data-content='" . $app_about . "<a href=\"./games.php?play_error#library\">...</a><br /><br /><center><a href=\"./games.php?play_error#library\" class=\"btn btn-info\"><i class=\"icomoon-white icomoon-screen\"></i> Play in browser</a></center>'>";
      } else if (!empty($row['app_about']) === true && strlen($row['app_about']) <= 100) {
        echo "<a href='#!' class='thumbnail minigamedesc' title='" . $row['app_name'] . "' data-content='" . $row['app_about'] . "<br /><br /><center><a href=\"./play.php?app=" . $row['app_id'] . "\" class=\"btn btn-info\"><i class=\"icomoon-white icomoon-screen\"></i> Play in browser</a></center>'>";
      } else if (!empty($row['app_about']) === true && strlen($row['app_about']) >= 101) {
        $app_about = substr(strip_tags($row['app_about']), 0, 100);
        echo "<a href='#!' class='thumbnail minigamedesc' title='" . $row['app_name'] . "' data-content='" . $app_about . "<a href=\"./play.php?app=" . $row['app_id'] . "\">...</a><br /><br /><center><a href=\"./play.php?app=" . $row['app_id'] . "\" class=\"btn btn-info\"><i class=\"icomoon-white icomoon-screen\"></i> Play in browser</a></center>'>";
      } else {
        echo "<a href='#!' class='thumbnail minigamedesc' title='" . $row['app_name'] . "' data-content='Nothing to see here, yet ! <br /><br /><center><a href=\"./play.php?app=" . $row['app_id'] . "\" class=\"btn btn-info\"><i class=\"icomoon-white icomoon-screen\"></i> Play in browser</a></center>'>";
      }
      ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $row['app_preview']; ?>">
      <div class="minigames-caption">
        <h4><?php echo $row['app_name']; ?></h4>
        <p>By <?php echo $row['app_dev']; ?>.</p>
      </div>
      </a>
      <?php
      echo "</li>";
    }
      ?>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Added the code as it is right now to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of rows are limited, I would put the results into one array and then use `array_chunk()` to split them into portions.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

foreach (array_chunk($results, 4) as $chunk) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        echo '<li>', /*....*/, '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: This seems to have sealed the deal ! Thank you very much ! I will report back if I encounter any other problems with this particular code.

Answer (score 1):

Divide x by 4 and round it up. Eg 4/4 = 1, 5/4 = 2, 9/4 = 3. Then, use a for loop.

```
var noOfTimes = //x/4 rounded up

for (var i = 0; i < noOfTimes; i++) {
 //insert code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ceil` function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < ceil($num_rows / 4); $i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```